# Does anyone know what has caused the marks on this film? It came back from the developers like this

Tags: film, spots

Rollei Infrared Film (in date)

[image]

Comment: For me it looks like combination of air bubbles and nonhomogeneous developer liquid. Also can be manufacturing defect on the film emulsion.